# Does this differential equation have a formal solution in terms of an integral?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does the following differential equation have a formal solution in terms of an integral?

$$f(x)^2+f'(x)+V(x)=0$$

where $f'(x)=\frac{df(x)}{dx}$, $V(x)$ is some known function of $x$, and we want to solve for $f(x)$.

Comment: This is a Riccati equation. Set $f=\frac{u'}{u}$ to get $u''+V(x)u(x)=0$ and apply linear ODE theory.

Comment: @LutzL Actually, that is where I started initially and went to Riccati equation in hopes that one could say more about it in that form. ^^